# Logging in Azure App Service and nopCommerce

Tags: azure-web-app-service, nopcommerce

How can I wire up Azure App Service logging in nopCommerce?

I've tried following this blog post: [ASP.NET Core Logging with Azure App Service and Serilog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/26/asp-net-core-logging/) but I don't see where loggerFactory is used in nopCommerce.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking into version 4.0 or older, then *yes!* loggerFactory has not been used in that version. However, newer version (i.e version 4.1) is using it at few places.

Check current development branch at [here.](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/search?q=ILoggerFactory&unscoped_q=ILoggerFactory)